# Hide element after delay, then make it toggle-able?

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm looking to have an alert banner at the top of page be visible initially, then animate upwards after a delay.

Afterwards I'd like users to be able to toggle the element upwards or downwards.

Here's my html:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#foo').delay(3000).animate({
    top: "-150px",
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clickme').toggle(function() {
    $('#foo').animate({
      top: '-=120'
    }, 1000);
  },function() {
    $('#foo').animate({
      top: '+=120'
    }, 1000);
  })
});


</script>
</head>
<div id="foo">
It's a notification!
</div>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas
tortor arcu, sollicitudin et rutrum non, dapibus convallis est. Nulla in
est risus, sit amet consectetur eros. Aliquam posuere, tellus at cursus
pulvinar, mi nulla bibendum sapien, quis lobortis diam risus nec lectus.
Sed justo nunc, lacinia ac sagittis non, aliquam nec est. Praesent porta
neque sed erat vehicula id cursus quam semper.</p>
<button id="clickme">
  Click here
</button>
```

Comment: The two functions don't play together for some reason. Each works separately, but when they're both present, toggling isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't you forgot to specify "px" units for the manual animation?

```
 top: '-=120px'
```

Also, why are you using 2 "document ready" ?

Ok, here's an example that works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready( function() {


  $('#foo').delay(3000).animate({
    top: "-150px",
   }, 1000, function() {
     // Animation complete.
   });

  $('#clickme').toggle(function() {
     $('#foo').animate({
       top: '0'
     }, 1000);
  },function() {
     $('#foo').animate({
       top: '-150px'
     }, 1000);
  });


 });

</script>
```

And don't forget to add this:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    #foo {position: absolute;}
 </style>
```

... since you're animating top property.

Comment: OK. I specified "px". As to why 2 document ready, I'm a novice... Here's my updated code, still with the same behaviour: `$(document).ready( function() {
        $('#foo').delay(1000).animate({
    top: "-150px",
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
      });
      
      

     $('#clickme').toggle(function() {
       $('#foo').animate({
          top: '-=120px'
        }, 1000);
       },function() {
       $('#foo').animate({
          top: '+=120px'
        }, 1000);
   });`

Comment: **I'm clearly having some trouble formatting my StackOverflow comments as well :(

Comment: I made a simple test that worked well on my local machine. Check out my revised example.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Still not sure what exactly was wrong with my code (position:absolute was taken care of). Am I missing some quirk of nesting/chaining in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Really, it's working. The problem :

firdt .ready() ->  top: "-150px",

must be ->  top: "-=150px",

and add  style="top: 500px; position: absolute" to #foo

Why? because #foo was positioned out of visible document ... ;)